# Launching X11 application (Firefox) via crontab

Tags: shell, centos, x11, cron

I want to write a crontab that opens Firefox every minute (just to test it, I know it doesn't make any sense).
My problem is that even though crontab is active nothing happens.
This is how my crontab looks like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=~/bin:/usr/bin:bin
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 xhost localuser /usr/bin/firefox
```

Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: Is there any error in the `cron`'s log file ?

Comment: This link http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it will likely help you solve your problem. If it does not it will help you gather information that will help us help you. You should edit that information into your question. Note too that in general SF does not accept workstation questions.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> export DISPLAY=:0.0 xhost localuser /usr/bin/firefox
> ```

Just from looking at the above cron command, I can see why it won’t work. The usage for the `export` command is

```
export name[=word]...
```

In POSIX shells, the rest of the words following `export DISPLAY=:0.0` will be treated as other shell variables that should be exported to the environment – not commands that will be run.  POSIX (Issue 7, 2018 edition) also specifies that a [name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235) should be

> a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the
>   portable character set.

This means that shell variable names can not contain characters such as `/` so attempting to include `/usr/bin/firefox` among the list of variable names to be exported would throw an error with a message such as `not a valid identifier` or `bad variable name`.

---

Also, the `xhost` command is used incorrectly. Run `xhost` by itself to see if you need to add your user account as an allowed user. This should only need to be run once and shouldn’t be scheduled by cron.

---

Unless there’s some other mechanism preventing programs from connecting to the X display server, the above lines can simply be replaced with:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
* * * * * /usr/bin/firefox
```

This should launch a new Firefox window every minute. There’s also no need to
specify the `SHELL` environment variable – and since you’re specifying the full path for the `firefox` executable, there’s no need to set the `PATH` variable either.

---

See also: [POSIX specification for `export`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export)